# Dynamically change the color of the path on Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to dynamically change the color of the path when an agent is walking on it, like leaving a trail behind him, or indicating where he should go

I tried a code that was proposed in another similar problems with IfOccupied but didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the color of a `Path` using `myPath.setLineColor(green)`. Other things you can do are described [in the help](https://anylogic.help/markup/path-mhl.html#functions).